# Unity3D Collision with character controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm new to unity and i'm trying to make an endless runner. When my player (a ball) hits one of the walls the game needs to go the scene: LostMenu. My problem is that the collision doesn't work. Nothing happens when they collide... Here are the inspectors on both the player and the walls: Walls http://prntscr.com/a2pgzm Player http://prntscr.com/a2ph66 .

The collision script on the walls:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LostByWallCSR : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
             Application.LoadLevel("LostMenu");
             Debug.Log ("WORKS!");
        }
   }
}
```

The movement script on the player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControllerz : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 5f;
public float gravity = 20f;
private Vector3 moveDirections = new Vector3();
private Vector3 inputs = new Vector3();

void FixedUpdate()
{
    CharacterController cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (cc.isGrounded) 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
            inputs.z = 3;
        else if (Input.GetKey("right"))
            inputs.z = -3;
        else
            inputs.z = 0;

        moveDirections = transform.TransformDirection(inputs.x, 0, inputs.z) * speed;                    
    }

    inputs.x = 5;
    moveDirections.y = inputs.y - gravity;
    cc.Move(moveDirections * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Any idea on how to setup the collision properly? Attaching a rigibody is not helping it. Unless i'm missing something ofcourse.

Comment: Without attaching rigidbody on both bodies OnCollision will not work

Comment: So, you are telling me I need to attach a RigidBody AND a CharacterController on my player? I don't think those things work together very well...

Comment: Attach rigidbidy to your wall instead

Comment: Okay, if I start the game and immedtiatly collide with it everything works. The problem is that the wall is kind of colliding with other walls and he 'flies' away. He totally gets pushed away because of the rigidbody and those physics. If I however try to chase it while it gets pushed away and collide with it, nothing works. So it only works in its original state. Any idea how to remove that he gets pushed away by the other walls? Setting 'Is Kinematic' removes the pushing, but then the collision doesn't work anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103374/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-belgianwizard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both objects have a collider component.

You need to attach a **rigidbody** component to one of the objects.(if you don't attach rigid body it will not work)

your Sphere collider is Trigger , remove that or change your function to

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **OnControllerColliderHit** method

```
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Trap"))
    {
        Debug.Log("colisiono with trap");
        playerDentro = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Trap"))
        {
            Debug.Log("player salio de la trampa");
            playerDentro = false;
        }
    }
}e
```